# Add a string to each line that the user won't be able to mark

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add the string ">>>" to each line of text, but I don't want my user to be able to mark it when he copies the text.

The only way I could think of is replacing a bullet list with the string. But it doesn't work properly:

```css
ul.codeline {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.codeline li {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

ul.codeline li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2em;
  content: ">>> ";
}
```

```html
<ul class="codeline">
  <li>function foo() {</li>
  <li>console.log('bar')</li>
  <li>}</li>
</ul>
```

Any other suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Pseudo-element

Comment: [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) accepts a string, or you could set it to `none` and use pseudo-elements.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the use case?
If you can affect the page using Javascript, you can create an event that listens on when a user copies your text and delete the ">>>" string.

Comment: Added an example snippet, feel free to edit it to suit your current usage, because it appears to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably using the list and including a pseudo-element for each `li`, which can't be selected:

**CSS:**

```
ul.codeline li::before
  content: '>>> ';
}
```

Another solution using **JavaScript** could look like this:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
  var str = window.getSelection().toString().replace(/>/g, '');

  e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', str);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

This code allows you to modify the user's selection and filter out `>>>`, so it doesn't show when they paste their selection again.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!
I added a line that'll cancel the bullet as well:

ul.codeline {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.codeline li::before {
  content: '>>> ';
}